# TSQL If Exists within subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that is working as expected however I want to see it the `submissionID` exists within another table. Here is what my current query looks like.

```
IF (@action = 'filter')
            BEGIN

                --Get the current active voting session
                DECLARE @session INT
                SET @session = (SELECT sessionID 
                FROM empowermentSessions 
                WHERE status = '1')

                SELECT A.[submissionID],
                       A.[subEmpID],
                       A.[nomineeEmpID],
                       CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
                       A.[situation],
                       A.[task],
                       A.[action],
                       A.[result],
                       A.[timestamp],
                       A.[statusID],
                       A.[approver],
                       A.[approvalDate],
                       B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
                       B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
                       B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
                       C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
                       C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
                       D.[categoryName],
                       (

                       --If exists return true else false
                        select submissionID 
                        from empowermentEntries
                        where sessionID = @session



                       )
                FROM   empowermentSubmissions AS A
                       INNER JOIN
                       empTable AS B
                       ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
                       INNER JOIN
                       empTable AS C
                       ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
                       INNER JOIN
                       empowermentCategories AS D
                       ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]
                WHERE  (A.[categoryID] = @category or @category = '')
                AND (A.[nomineeDepartment] = @department or @department = '')
                AND A.[submissionDate] >= @startDate and A.[submissionDate] <= @endDate
                FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

You will notice I have a sub select in there where I was starting this and then couldn't figure it out from there. I need to see if the submission ID exists in that other table and if it does, return true for the XML value else False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do this with a subselect. You are effectively checking if your variable @session has a value. Also you can modify how you set that variable a little bit simpler.

```
DECLARE @session INT
SELECT @session = sessionID 
FROM empowermentSessions 
WHERE status = '1'

SELECT A.[submissionID],
       A.[subEmpID],
       A.[nomineeEmpID],
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
       A.[situation],
       A.[task],
       A.[action],
       A.[result],
       A.[timestamp],
       A.[statusID],
       A.[approver],
       A.[approvalDate],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
       B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
       B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
       C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
       C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
       D.[categoryName],
       case when @session IS NULL then 'false' else 'true' end
FROM   empowermentSubmissions AS A
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS B
       ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empTable AS C
       ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
       INNER JOIN
       empowermentCategories AS D
       ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]
WHERE  (A.[categoryID] = @category or @category = '')
AND (A.[nomineeDepartment] = @department or @department = '')
AND A.[submissionDate] >= @startDate and A.[submissionDate] <= @endDate
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: I have multiple sessions in the sessions table but only one of them can be active at a time. I need to get the sessionID of the active session. I then use this ID to find out if the submissionID exists with that sessionID. Confusing I'm sure

Comment: Right I sort of assumed you would have only 1. This code will work fine for that. Look at the variable. If there are no rows returned then the value will be NULL. There is no need to query the table again.

Comment: I may not be explaining it correctly. I am first finding the active `sessionID` in the first select. I then need to find out if the `submissionID` from the main select exists in another table called `empowermentEntries`. `@Session` will always return true as there will always be an active session. However, I need to find out if the `submissionID` exists in `empowermentEntries` table for the active `@session`

Comment: Maybe this would help you understand my setup : http://oi62.tinypic.com/5dvryt.jpg

Comment: OK. Then just add a left join to empowermentEntries. Then you can use a modified case expression. "case when statusID = '1' then 'True' else 'False' end"

Comment: Something like this.

SELECT
...
case ess.status when '1' then 'True' else 'False' end
FROM   empowermentSubmissions AS es
INNER JOIN empTable AS e ON es.[nomineeEmpID] = e.[empID]
INNER JOIN empTable AS e2 ON es.[subEmpID] = e2.[empID]
INNER JOIN empowermentCategories AS ec ON es.[categoryID] = ec.[catID]
left join empowermentEntries ee on ee.submissionID = es.submissionID
left join empowermentSessions ess on ess.sessionID = ee.sessionID

Comment: wow I don't like the way you can't format comments...notice I also changed your aliases. You really should try to avoid using a,b,c as aliases. This makes debugging your own code very painful. Give your tables reasonable abbreviations. You will soon find that you reuse the same aliases for a given table repeatedly.  It will make your life a lot easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have a bool type.  You can do this with a case.

```
CASE WHEN (select count(1) 
from empowermentEntries
where sessionID = @session) > 0 THEN 'true' else 'false' end
```

If the row exists you will get a count of 1 or more which will put 'true' in the column.  If it doesn't exist you will get zero back which will return 'false'.

You could also left join to empowermentEntries and avoid the subselect entirely.

Comment: this kinda works however I am using XML path so not sure how to define the tag for this. It just prints the value at the end of it so I know its working but I need to define that tag as `<inVoting>true</inVoting>`

Comment: Then add that to the string I guess.  THEN '<inVoting>true</inVoting>' ELSE <inVoting>false</inVoting>

Comment: Yea I tried that already, print the entities for the </> instead of creating the tags

Comment: @SBB What do you mean by that?  Can you show me the result you do expect?

Comment: Supposed to be as shown above but is  returned like this `&lt;inVoting&gt;true&lt;/inVoting&gt;`

Comment: That is html encoding.  Can you decode in the app?  What language are you using to call the SP?